# Spring Boot: file upload testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a Unit test in a Spring REST application.  the test is related to an endpoint for MultipartFile uploading.

Here is the arguments that my method accepts within my `@RestController`

```java
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity uploadFile(@HasFileName @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                     @NotEmpty @RequestParam("entity") String entity, @NotEmpty @RequestParam("language") String language,
                                     @NotEmpty @RequestParam("lastModified") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime lastModifiedDateTime,
                                     @NotEmpty @RequestParam("createdDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime createdDateTime)
            throws IOException {
```

I can't find a way to get this information from the multipart inside the unit test. I can't find documentation on making spring unit test for Spring REST, so any inputs would be appreciated.

```java
@Test
    public void testUploadFile() throws Exception{
        ResultMatcher ok = MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk();

        String filename = "test.txt";
        File file = new File("/test" + filename);

        file.delete();

        MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "test.txt", "multipart/form-data", "test data".getBytes());

        upload.uploadFile(mockMultipartFile, mockMultipartFile.getName()) //missing more data

        //more logic on how to assert that the file is not empty 


    }
```

Comment: check out this test class --> https://github.com/FineUploader/spring-boot-server/blob/master/src/test/java/com/fineuploader/web/FineUploaderControllerTest.java

Answer (score 0):

In principle the test should validate the outcome of the uploadFile method():

```
ResultActions result = 
this.mockMvc.perform(multipart("/svc").file(file)
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
            "Bearer token"))
        .andExpect(content().string("response"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

The file is an input parameter so I dont understand why you want to verify it is not empty: it could be useful I believe to verify the interactions with other mocks (for instance checking the file is used in a FileService.save() method)

Comment: One more note: if you mock a service class that uses the File you could verify the parameter is not empty, but this only makes sense if the parameter is manipulated/prepared within the RestController.
See Mockito ArgumentCaptor